# Angular FormControl data is not updating from the view

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to read the data from a FormGroup with ReactiveFormsModule. However, I am having trouble, and the value of the form's fields is always empty.

I have a route loading a submodule 'ByHModule' and in this one another route for each component. In this case 'cartera'

```
...
path: 'Cartera',
component: CarteraComponent,
...
```

I have loaded the FormsModule and the ReactiveFormsModule in the byh.modules.ts which routes to the 'Cartera' component. Once loaded it shows a form with one text input and one textarea. I want to get the data of the form when it is submitted.

The code of the CarteraComponent is as follows:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-byh-cartera',
  templateUrl: 'byh-cartera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./byh-cartera.component.scss'],
})
export class CarteraComponent implements OnInit{

  nuevaCarteraForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.nuevaCarteraForm = this.fb.group({
      nombre: [''],
      extra: ['']
      });
  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){

  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.nuevaCarteraForm.value));
  }
}
```

The 'byh-cartera.component.html':

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <nb-card>
            <nb-card-header></nb-card-header>
            <nb-card-body>
                <form [formGroup]= "nuevaCarteraForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Nombre de la cartera" FormControlName="nombre">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <textarea rows="5" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Comentarios" FormControlName="extra">{{nuevaCarteraForm.value | json}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Crear</button>

                </form>
            </nb-card-body>
        </nb-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on Submit the console shows: {"nombre":"","extra":""} not matter what I write in the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML change `FormControlName` to `formControlName` and pass your form to the submit.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <nb-card>
                <nb-card-header></nb-card-header>
                <nb-card-body>
                    <form [formGroup]= "nuevaCarteraForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(nuevaCarteraForm)" novalidate>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Nombre de la cartera" formControlName="nombre">
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <textarea rows="5" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Comentarios" formControlName="extra">{{nuevaCarteraForm.value | json}}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Crear</button>

                    </form>
                </nb-card-body>
            </nb-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
onSubmit(form: FormControl){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, it was just the lower case in formControlName. The second part is not mandatory, the 'nuevaCarteraForm' variable contains the values of the form so it can be just: console.log(JSON.stringify(this.nuevaCarteraForm.value)). But thank you very much!